# How to get address of user-defined function?

Tags: c++, c, windows, hook

I am trying to hook a user-defined function. *(via DLL injection and inline function hooking)*
To do that, I need to get the address of the function to hook in process memory.

I tried various methods to find the address, and finally came up with the equation below.

> (offset) = (Address of function in EXE file) - (Image base of EXE file)

> (Address of function in process memory) = (GetModuleHandle(NULL)) + (offset)

However, I am not sure if this equation always holds. *(For example, when DLL Relocation occurs, I am worried that this equation may be wrong.)*

**In conclusion,** I want to know whether this equation always holds. And if not, I'd like to know how to fix this equation.

*(This article has been translated by Google Translate.)*

---

< testwinapi / main.cpp >

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void capture(HBITMAP* canvas);

int APIENTRY WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd) {
    while(1) {
        HBITMAP canvas;
        capture(&canvas);
        Sleep(2000);
    }

    return 0;
}

void capture(HBITMAP* canvas) {
    RECT srcRect;
    HWND hSrcWnd;
    HDC hSrcDC, hDestDC;

    hSrcWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    hSrcDC = GetDC(hSrcWnd);

    GetWindowRect(hSrcWnd, &srcRect);
    int SrceenWidth = srcRect.right - srcRect.left;
    int SrceenHeight = srcRect.bottom - srcRect.top;

    hDestDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hSrcDC);
    *canvas = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hSrcDC, SrceenWidth, SrceenHeight);
    SelectObject(hDestDC, *canvas);

    for (int y = 0; y < SrceenHeight; y += 50) {
        BitBlt(hDestDC, 0, y, SrceenWidth, 50, hSrcDC, 0, y, SRCCOPY);
        Sleep(2);
    }

    ReleaseDC(hSrcWnd, hSrcDC);
    DeleteDC(hDestDC);
}
```

< testdll / dllmain.cpp >

```
#include "pch.h"

DWORD WriteLog(LPCTSTR format, ...);
void MyCapture(HBITMAP* canvas);

void(*originFunc)(HBITMAP*) = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(HBITMAP*)>(0x941880); //Address of function in process memory

DWORD WriteLog(LPCTSTR lpszFormat, ...) {
    TCHAR szLog[512];
    DWORD dwCharsWritten;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, lpszFormat);
    _vstprintf_s(szLog, 512, lpszFormat, args);
    va_end(args);

    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), szLog, _tcslen(szLog), &dwCharsWritten, NULL);

    return dwCharsWritten;
}

void MyCapture(HBITMAP* canvas) {
    WriteLog(TEXT("Function called : capture(0x%X)\n"), (DWORD)canvas);
    return originFunc(canvas);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    if (DetourIsHelperProcess())
        return TRUE;

    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        AllocConsole();
        DetourRestoreAfterWith();
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)originFunc, MyCapture);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        FreeConsole();
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)originFunc, MyCapture);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

< testdll / pch.cpp >

```
#include "pch.h"
```

< testdll / pch.h >

```
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

#include "framework.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <detours.h> 
//MS Detours library 
//Can be downloaded from NuGet Package Manager

#endif
```

< testdll / framework.h >

```
#pragma once

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
```

< DLL Injector >
https://github.com/DarthTon/Xenos/releases/latest

---

After injecting 'testdll.dll' into 'testwinapi.exe', I want to be able to monitor the 'capture' function call. (Because the 'capture' function is reconstructed by reverse engineering, it is assumed that there is no source code for 'testwinapi.exe')

---

[image: Image base of EXE file]

[image: Address of function in EXE file]

---

[image: GetModuleHandle(NULL)]

[image: Address of function in process memory]

Comment: I suppose you want to hack an other process, not the current one ?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: What's wrong with `GetProcAddress`?

Comment: @IInspectable //  It is impossible because the function trying to get the address is not defined in the dll.

Comment: @tadman // Sorry. I've added the source code and some explanation to the article.

Comment: @bruno // Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module relocation occurs as a whole. Individual sections are never moved with respect to the image base. The offsets (RVA) of each section are hardcoded in the module header.

For example:

```
#  Name   VirtSize RVA      PhysSize Offset
1 .text   000C44C1 00001000 000C4600 00000800
2 .data   00000FEC 000C6000 00000E00 000C4E00
3 .rsrc   00000520 000C7000 00000600 000C5C00
4 .reloc  0000B098 000C8000 0000B200 000C6200
```

These sections are loaded at specified RVA offsets, regardless of image base address. There's also the implicit "header" section with RVA 0 and size 0x1000, which is why the first section starts at 0x1000. Note that RVA offset != file offset.

So yes, given some known image base and an address inside of it, the offset of that address from the image base will remain constant.

This allows 64-bit code to employ RIP-relative addressing into the .data section, for example, which saves a fixup.

Comment: Is this also true for JIT-compiled code running in the CLR?

Comment: @IInspectable This answer applies to native code only. I only know that addresses given out by GetProcAddress are constant and JIT-compiled code can be recompiled at any time, thus I assume there would be some trampoline at a fixed address that jumps to the JIT code. Don't know enough about CLR inner workings to answer that definitively.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the intervals of the CLR either, but I do recall that - unlike Java - .NET code gets JIT-compiled at most once.